# Big O properties

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm studying some properties about "Big O". I begin to understand the idea behind of this but have some trouble with the following equality: 
$$O(1/n)=O(1/n^{2})$$

I don't understand it. I would like to prove that exist constants $M,N$ such as $1/n\leq M/n^{2}$ and $N/n\geq 1/n^{2}$ from some $n\geq k$ but I can't achieve it.

Some ideas to solve it?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: We can never find such constant $M$, and strictly to say, we only define $f(n)=O(g(n))$, but not $O(f(n))=O(g(n))$ alone, what is your context actually?

Answer (score 1):

$O(g(n))$ represents a class of functions, roughly speaking, the functions of $n$, which divided by $g(n)$, in absolute value, are bounded as $n$ approaches to infinity.

Then when we write $O(g(n))=O(h(n))$ we mean that, a function $f$ which is in $O(g(n))$ *is also* in $O(h(n))$. It is NOT a symmetric notion: writing $O(h(n))=O(g(n))$ we intend a different thing (interchange $g$ and $h$ in the sentence above).

So in our context the meaning is: a function which is a $O(1/n)$ is also a $O(1/n^2)$ for $n\to\infty$. Which is false (for example $f(n):=1/n$ is a $O(1/n)$ but it isn't a $O(1/n^2)$). The correct claim is $O(1/n^2)=O(1/n)$, i.e. a function which is in $O(1/n^2)$ is also in $O(1/n)$ as you can verify easily.